# Pagination in Archives

Tags: pagination

Hello I am new to wordpress and I suck at it. I am trying to add numbered pagination to my blog page in wordpress. I downloaded the plug in 'page navi' and went into my editor and changed a file in index.php to:

```
    <?php if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>

        <div class="post-nav archive-nav">
            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>

            <div class="clear"></div>

        </div> <!-- /post-nav archive-nav -->

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Now nothing displays for page navigation. I have been trying for some time to add numbered pagination to my older posts and I keep screwing up. What should I do?( Please be detailed in your response like you're talking to an infant because the information I have found online has so far proven useless.)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer exactly, because themes vary. But typically index.php is not the one that is used for your blog archive / front page. It is there as a fallback. Many themes have a "front-page.php" or a "home.php" that contains the blog archive / front page code. If you have a static front page (you set a Page in wp-admin as the homepage) you may also need to look for an archive template, possibly "archive.php". I would try going through these files and just add a bit of text - that way you'll know when you have the right file, even if a function isn't working as expected. The [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) may help you determine which file you need to be editing.

Once you've found the right file, it will be easier to add the navigation - though you should be able to use the built-in [posts_nav_link()](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) function rather than having to install Page Navi or any other plugins.

Since you're new to WP, also look into [child themes](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/) if you haven't yet. Rather than directly editing any of your theme files, you create a child theme so that any changes you make will still be applied. If you edit a theme directly, then whenever it is updated, your changes will all be overwritten.